# Using Promises inside nested for loops in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, excel, asynchronous

I am still in learning stage of Node.js and I have a scenario where in

I have 3 tables in mysql **category**, **subcategory** and **items** which has name and id for all rows.

Now,I have have list of folders and some .xlsx files in every folder and some sheets in every .xlsx file

Where the foldername is the categoryname in the category tables

.xlsx filename is the subcategoryname in the subcategory table and
the sheet name inside every .xlsx file is the itemname in the items table

What I want to do is I need to loop through every folder,file and sheet and crete a mapping table of there Id's .

my code so far :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const xlsx = require('node-xlsx').default;
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = require('./db-connection.js');

var categoryMapping = () => {

//directory of all files
var mainDirectory = `${__dirname}/xlsx/final_data`;

//reading mainDirectory
fs.readdir(mainDirectory, function(err, files) {

    if (err) {
        console.error("Could not list the directory.", err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    files.forEach(function(file, index) {

        //taking the folder name and getting the id of that name
        var sql = 'SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE xxx = ' + mysql.escape(file);

        connection.query(sql, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            if (result.length > 0) {
                console.log('cat id:', result[0].CategoryId);
            } else {
                //fs.appendFile('category.log',`${file} not present in xxx table` + '\n');
                console.log(`${file} not present in xxx table`);
            }
        });

        //directory of .xlxs files
        var subCategoryDirectory = path.join(mainDirectory, file);

        fs.readdir(subCategoryDirectory, function(err, sheets) {

            if (err) {
                console.error("Could not list the directory.", err);
                process.exit(1);
            }

            sheets.forEach(function(sheet, index) {

                //taking the file name and getting the id of that name
                var filename = path.parse(sheet).name;

                var sql = 'SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE xxx = ' + mysql.escape(filename);

                connection.query(sql, function(error, result) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    if (result.length > 0) {
                        console.log('sub cat id:', result[0].SubCategoryId);
                    } else {
                        //fs.appendFile('sub-category.log', `${filename} in ${subCategoryDirectory} not present in xxx table` + '\n');
                        console.log(`${filename} not present in xxx table`);
                    }
                });

                //individual .xlxs file path
                var sheetpath = path.join(subCategoryDirectory, sheet);

                const fileData = xlsx.parse(sheetpath);

                fileData.forEach(function(page, index) {

                    //taking the sheet name and getting the id of that name
                    var itemName = page.name;
                    var sql = 'SELECT SaltId FROM master_ddb_salts WHERE SaltName = ' + mysql.escape(itemName);

                    connection.query(sql, function(error, result) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                        if (result.length > 0) {
                            console.log('item id:', JSON.stringify(result[0].ItemId));
                        } else {
                            //fs.appendFile('salts.log', `${itemName} of ${sheetpath} not present in salt-master table` + '\n');
                            console.log(`${itemName} not present in xxx table`);
                        }
                    });

                    //maybe here I need to enter all categoryId, subCategoryId and itemId to mapping table 

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
};

categoryMapping();
```

My code so far is giving me all the ID's properly.

I know the basic usage of **Promises** but I am not getting how to implement it here.

Could someone explain how can I make use of Promises or Callbacks here?
Any better solutions like making use of npm pakages like Q,bluebird or async are aslo OK.